# Matplotlib: Keep plots at a single size

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a multiple plot figure - which is great. Except when I run it, the graphs will maintain the same size font etc, even if that means overlap. I just want 3 nice graphs that maintain their size all the time. I've attached the image of what I get and also an image of how I'd like each individual graph to look (based on a single plot).

Any suggestions would be great - since I have a deadline and this is driving me insane.

[Single plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a78K.png)
[Multi-Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzjBC.jpg)

I have tried using plt.tight_layout() and had no luck.

The basic code for any individual plot is:

```
def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax, offset):
    ax.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", offset))
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

# First create your figure, with 3 subplots sharing the x axis.
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True, figsize = 
(8.27,11.69), dpi = 100)
fig.tight_layout()

# make some room on the right for the twin axes
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8, hspace=0.0001)


# The easy ones, create the first twin axes on ax1 and ax2
ax1t = ax1.twinx()
ax2t = ax2.twinx()

x = data['elapsed_seconds']

# Plot
#--------Raw data + Abutment Stress
ax1.scatter(x, Abut_Stress, label='Abutment Stress Calculated', linewidth=0, 
marker='o', s=20, c='k')
ax1.plot(x, data['wheel_temp_c'], label='Wheel Temperature', linestyle="-", 
color='b')
ax1.plot(x, data['abut_temp_c'], label='Abutment Temperature', linestyle="- 
", color='g')
ax1t.plot(x, data['wheel_speed'], label='Wheel Speed', linestyle="-", 
color='r')

h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax1t.get_legend_handles_labels()
lg = ax1.legend(h1 + h2, l1 + l2, bbox_to_anchor=(0., 0.8, 1., .102), loc=3, 
ncol=1, borderaxespad=0.)
#lg.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.5)

ax1.set_ylabel(r"Abutment Stress (MPa)    Temperature($^\circ$C)")
ax1t.set_ylabel(r"Wheel Speed (RPM)")
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to tinker with the fontsizes of the ticks, labels and the legend size yourself

Comment: @DavidG Ahhh, not to worry. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Rather than doing it for each subplot you could set the `rcparams` for the whole python script. E.g. https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams

Comment: A few ideas - you could put line breaks in your axis labels, so they wrap on to two lines, you could reduce font size of the labels, and move them outside the plots, you could also alternate the side that the y-axis appears on, so they don't overlap. Finally, you could put some horizontal padding between your plots. If you can provide some mock data, I could take a look.